# How to find pagenumber of current page of PDF inside web form using object tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an application where a PDF file is opened inside the web form as shown in the below code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
        </div>
        <div id="divPDF" runat="server">
    <object data="<%=pdfPath%>" type="application/pdf" style="height:500px; width: "500px" >
    </object>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

protected string pdfPath;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    divPDF.Visible = false;
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.FileName != "")
    {
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName));
        pdfPath = FileUpload1.FileName;
        divPDF.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

It is working fine and I can view and read the `pdf`. Now what I need is when I scroll through the pages the current `pagenumber` should appear in a text box.

Comment: maybe you can find something if you use the adobe reader activex plugin: download the sdk (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/sdk/eula.html) - \Documentation\Javascript\js_api_reference.pdf - page 366 "embedded pdf"